# codename one animate forground of label

Tags: label, codenameone, opacity, foreground

This does not work for me.  I am attempting to change the color
when I press the button.

```
 Form hi = new Form("Layout Animations", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    Button button = new Button("button");

    Label l = new Label(" ");
    l.setUIID("DestinationUIID");
    l.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0xff0000);

    Label l$ = new Label("Label");
    l$.setUIID("DestinationUIID");
    l$.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0x00ff00);

    hi.add(l$);

    ComponentAnimation ca = l$.createStyleAnimation("DestinationUIID", 2000);
    l$.getAnimationManager().addAnimation(ca, () -> onCompletion());

    button.addActionListener((e) -> {

        //l$.animate();
        l$.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0xff0000);
         l$.animate();
        //hi.getContentPane().animateHierarchyFade(2000, 0);
    });
    hi.add(button);
    hi.show();
```

I don't understand the concept of a UIID, or the syntax for animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to animate the foreground from style animation to `animate()` calls to `UITimer`.

Using style animations we can do something like this for a 500ms transition:

```
ComponentAnimation ca = myLabel.createStyleAnimation("DestinationUIID", 500);
myLabel.getAnimationManager().addAnimation(ca, () -> onCompletion());
```

Comment: You advised another user, "You need to create a source UIID and destination UIID as we use them to reset the state."  However, we are both confused about the syntax of how to do that.  I don't understand the concept of animation in java, or the concept of a UIID...

Comment: The UIID is defined in the theme so you need to open the theme in the designer by opening the theme.res file and using `Add` to add entries defining the look of your component see: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/theme-basics.html Once you do that you can just apply something like this animation to transition between the two states. So assuming you have a `Button` with the `Button` UIID you can transition it to `ButtonRed` which you can define to derive from the `Button` theme while overriding fgColor to red.